# How to get parent view from partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial view as part of the _Layout.cshtml, so that it gets rendered on multiple pages. Think of the partial view as a menu that gets displayed on every page on the website.

When one of these links in the menu of the partial view is clicked, I can only access/see in the Action Method that gets called the partial view, like it's name etc.

But what I really need to have is the View that the partial view was on when the item was clicked.

How can I get this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly.. you want to get the name of the view that the partial view is being rendered on? Isn't it rendered in the layout?

Comment: That's correct: I'm on a certain page that has the partial view, and I want to know what that certain page is. 


These links that I was talking about are language settings, so I want to set the language in the action method and then redirect back to the page it came from (in a different language).

To do this, I have a separate controller to handle this, but I only get the partial view, not the view on which it was.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [ParentActionContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.parentactionviewcontext.aspx)

For example

```
 var controller = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] as string;
 var action = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] as string;
```

**Update**

From the view this call should do what you need

```
@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()
@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
```

Comment: ParentActionViewContext seems to be null in my Action Method, so no luck there... + Spaceballs is great - "I didn't see you playing with your dolls again!"

Comment: I think my mistake is that the code works in the controller, I've updatetd to use a different call from the view (BTW Sapeceball FTW :))