# In MVC, can I get the URL not the current action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

When my user navigates to this view `localhost/Keyword/MainView` which displays a partial view containing a form, I would like the controller action for the partial view to be able to see the URL of the MainView, not the partial view, and refresh it.

So, if I have a view like this (`MainView.cshtml`):

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div id="keywordGroupList">
                @{ Html.RenderAction("_KeywordGroupList", "Keyword"); }
            </div>
            <div id="keywordGroupCreate">
                @{ Html.RenderAction("_KeywordGroupCreate", "Keyword"); }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="keywordGroupEdit" class="col-md-9">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my partial view (`_KeywordGroupCreate.cshtml`):

```
@using System.Collections
@model PublicationSystem.Model.KeywordGroup
@{
    Layout = "";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm
        (
            "_KeywordGroupCreate",
            "Keyword",
            FormMethod.Post,
            new { id = "keywordGroupCreateForm" }
        )
    )  
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    //...
}
```

I would like the _KeywordGroupCreate action in the controller to do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult _KeywordGroupCreate(KeywordGroup model)
{
    db.KeywordGroup.Add(model);

    //return View();
    return RedirectToLocal(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
}
public ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Submission");
}
```

But right now `Request.Url.AbsolutePath` is coming back as '~/keyword/_keywordgroupcreate/f12345cf-xxxx-yyyy-zzzz-000000000000'

How can I get the full/parent/top level URL, `localhost/Keyword/MainView`?

*Update:*

The reason I would like to determine the parent view is because I may use this partial view in other places. So, in this example the parent view is `MainView.cshtml`, but I may also want the partial view to be used in `UserKeywords.cshtml`. So, I guess what I'm asking is to enable the partial view's submit/action to refresh the parent view, whatever the parent view is.

Comment: not sure ..may be this can help ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900820/how-to-get-parent-view-from-partial-view  with this you can construct your parent controller URL

Answer (score 0):

Why not redirecting for the main view action ?

Instead of :

```
return RedirectToLocal(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
```

Why not :

```
return RedirectToAction("MainView", "Keyword");
```

Maybe I dindnt get the question right.

Comment: MainView may be the current view, but there may be an instance where the PartialView is used in another view. Let me update my example.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath`

Comment: I've created a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660347/when-to-use-request-url-and-request-urlreferrer-in-mvc

Comment: I edit my response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32659853/3202657 please try and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score -1):

Change your partial view (_KeywordGroupCreate) adding the url as routeValues :

```
  @using System.Collections
  @model MVCApp.Controllers.KeywordGroup
  @{
     Layout = "";
  }
  @using (Html.BeginForm
          (
              "_KeywordGroupCreate",
              "Keyword",
              new { url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri },
              FormMethod.Post,
              new { id = "keywordGroupCreateForm" }
          )
      )
  {

     ...
  }
```

and get the value on your action controller post:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public ActionResult _KeywordGroupCreate(KeywordGroup model, string url)
  {
```

this will work for you, dont forget to vote!

Comment: In your code, `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` contains the URL of the partial view, not the parent view it is included on. The OP asked how to get the parent view URL.