# Alternative to using Request.URL and Request.URLReferrer to get the current link in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was hoping to write a method/property in my `BaseController` class that would enable any action to get the current URL. If I call `localhost/Keyword/Edit/1` I can use `Request.Url` to get the url. However, if there is a partial view in my Edit view, I need to use `Request.UrlReferrer` to get `localhost/Keyword/Edit/1`. If I use `Request.Url` while in the action for the partial view, I would end up with `localhost/Keyword/PartialView`.

Is there a built in way to always get the Url that would be in the browser address bar regardless of whether I'm in a View or Partial View?

Comment: Isn't `Request.UrlReferrer` `null` when you are not in a partial view?

Comment: It depends. If I go from /Home/Index to /Keyword/Index, UrlReferrer is `http://localhost/`. So, it seems to be the last Url you were at.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom HtmlHelper.Your HtmlHelper's ViewContext property will have just about everything you need about the particular request: HttpContext, RequestContext, RouteData, TempData, ViewData, etc.

To get the current path of the request, try `helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Path`

You can check the RouteData and obtain the (partial) action and controller, among other route values:

```
public static string TestHelper(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    var controller = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    var action = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    return controller + "/" + action;
}
```

If called in your Index view , it would return "Home/Index".

If called in your Partial view , it would return "Home/Partial".

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was actually hoping to find it in the controller, and do a Redirect. I would like some of my partial views will redirect to the parent, but the parent could be any number of views.