# How to get the file name of the .cshtml file that rendered a partial view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a view filed called Display.cshtml and a partial view called _AppMenu.cshtml. In the _AppMenu.cshtml,how would I pragmatically retrieve the file name for "Display.cshtml" the file that rendered it? The methods presented in the possible answer require that the action name is the same as the view which is not always true in my case.

Comment: `@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() + ".cshtml"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get parent view from partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900820/how-to-get-parent-view-from-partial-view)

Comment: Or you could try setting `ViewData` or `Viewbag` in "Display.cshtml" or all other views you have then read that in "_AppMenu.cshtml"

Comment: ViewData or Viewbag is not reliable enough there is a possibility that the values are not set and this is very manual. Sani, this only works if the view name matches the controller name.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve by getting the file name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Parent Model from partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322180/access-parent-model-from-partial-view)

Comment: @Jasen the thing about the XY Problem is that its diagnosis is often an XY Problem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
((RazorView)ViewContext.View).ViewPath
```